# Restrict write permissions for a field - Odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, usergroups

How can I restrict the write permissions for a field to a specific group ?

I want to check if a user is in a specific group with id 46. If the user is in this group, he should be allowed to write in this field. If he is not in this group, he should not be allowed to write.

The field is a custom field, editing the domain with the studio app I think I should avoid.

My field:

```
<field name="customer_codename" placeholder="Codename" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('customer_rank','=', 0),('is_company','=', False)]}"/>
```

I tried the following, but it did not work:
I created a new field using the studio app. Field type is boolean.
In the advanced properties I wanted to define the compute for the field. In dependencies I gave "user_id" and in the compute field I gave

```
for record in self:
  user_id.has_group('__export__.res_groups_46_eff9dc52')
```

The boolean field should be set to true if the user is in a certain group.

Comment: Have you tried with the name of the group instead of the id ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can give you the best answer there is.
But for me, I'd personally create a Boolean field in the view's associated model, with its default field a lambda function checking if the user belongs to the groups you mentioned.

Assuming `groups_id` is the name of the user groups in model `res.users`, we have:

```py
class ResUsers(models.Model): 
    _inherit = "res.users" 

    can_write_codename = fields.Boolean(default=lambda self: self.groups_id in ("model_name.group_name"))
```

Then in your xml file, you can include `can_write_codename` inside `attrs`, like this:

```xml
  <field name="customer_codename" placeholder="Codename" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('customer_rank','=', 0),('is_company','=', False)], 'readonly': [('can_write_codename', '=', 'True')]}"}"/>
```

Comment: I updated my question. I tried to define a computed field which should be set to true if the user is in a certain group.

Comment: So how did it go ? For me your approach is already good.